# Determining statistical significance in difference between two CRF models

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value

I have trained two Conditional Random Field (CRF) models `Ma` and `Mb` in CRF++, the first using a simple set of features, the second using a combination of the simple features and a more complex set of features.

I have run `crf_test` on my dev and test sets and computed precision, recall and F1-score.

I would like to know if the different results on the two models are statistically significant and the best way seems to be by employing a randomization approach to obtain a *p*-value. This approach is explained in ([Chindor, 1992](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1072064.1072068)) and further in ([Uzuner et al., 2007](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1975792)).

The articles state that given two models `Ma` and `Mb`, I should randomly shuffle their predicted labels over e.g. my development set to create a pair of pseudo-models `Pa` and `Pb`. The shuffling occurs by flipping a coin for each token in the development set. This should be repeated `N` times. `n` is defined as the number of times the difference in precision, recall and F1-score between `Pa` and `Pb` is greater than between `Ma` and `Mb`.

*p* can then be computed as `p = (n + 1) / (N + 1)`

I'm not exactly sure I understand this approach. Should I:

1. iterate over the two sets of predicted labels I got from running `crf_test` on my development set on models `Ma` and `Mb`
2. randomly switch the labels and let the resulting two sets of predicted labels be the pseudo-models `Pa` and `Pb`
3. recompute precision, recall and F1-score
4. calculate if difference in precision, recall and F1-score between the two shuffled sets of predicted labels is greater than between the two original sets of predicted labels - and if so increase `n` by 1
5. repeat this `N` times

Step 1 and 2 and 4 is what trips me up.

Comment: CRF? Please expand abbreviations on first use. There are several terms that have the abbreviation CRF.

Comment: Apologies. Conditional Random Fields.